# Rspec, create action, expected to have changed by 1, but was changed by 0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

My askings_controller.rb is below.

```
    class AskingsController < ApplicationController
        before_action :authenticate_user! , only: [:new , :create , :destroy]
        def create
          @asking=Asking.create(asking_params)  do |c|
             c.user=current_user
          end
          if @asking.save
           flash[:success] = "依頼に成功しました。"
           redirect_to @asking
          else
           render 'askings/new'
          end
        end
      end
```

My factories/askings.rb is below.

```
       FactoryGirl.define do
        factory :asking do
        association :user
        sequence(:content){|i| "お願いします#{i}"}
        lang "english"
        person 'ネイティブ限定'
        sex '男性限定'
        usepoint 1
        finished false
        title "MyString"
        deadline "2017-1-12"
        deadline_time 19
       end
     end
```

My askings_contoller_spec.rb is below.

```
  require 'rails_helper'
  RSpec.describe AskingsController, type: :controller do
   describe 'when login user' do
    context 'Post #create' do
      before do
          @user=create(:user)
          login_user(@user)
      end
      let(:asking_params) {attributes_for(:asking)}
      it 'should make askings +1' do
          expect{post :create, asking: asking_params}.to change(Asking, :count).by(1)
      end
    end
  end
```

My model/asking.rb is below.

```
     class Asking < ActiveRecord::Base
       belongs_to :user
       validates :title , presence: true , length: {maximum: 80}
       validates :content , presence: true , length: {maximum: 800}
       validates :lang , presence: true
       validates :usepoint , presence: true
       validates :person , presence: true
       validates :sex , presence: true
       validates :deadline , presence: true
       validates :deadline_time , presence: true
     end
```

Why do I have the error of 'expected #count to have changed by 1, but was changed by 0'?
When I remove 'validates :deadline_time , presence: true' from asking.rb , it works. But I think it isn't wrong.
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

In `factories/askings.rb` try to match the format of the deadline_time column. Right now you have the INT 19, perhaps try a string formatted for time (it would be nice to see the schema for Asking) .

Quick edit- My thought is that your factory is not making a valid asking, therefor the count is not increasing.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! but I'm sorry maybe , I don't understand what you mean.In factories/askings.rb , I show deadline_time with integer 19. and in model of Asking, I show the column of dealine_time with integer . Is it wrong?

Comment: I guess as long as they are matching datatypes it's okay, but I'd say it is a bit unconventional to save the time as an integer instead of Time or DateTime. Can you create a valid Asking in rails console by pasting this line: `Asking.create!(lang: "english", person: 'ネイティブ限定', sex: '男性限定', usepoint: 1, finished: false, title: "MyString", deadline: "2017-1-12", deadline_time: 19)`